# How to set cursor at the beginning of the txt file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Same as topic:
How to set cursor at the beginning of the txt file in the java? (im using scanner class)

Comment: ok, but there must be the other way to do that.. :P

Comment: `RandomAccessFile`, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you want...

Comment: Scanner doesn't offer that functionality, so no. You'll need to create a new one.

Comment: okej ill look up for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I interpreted the question wrong first.

I guess you can use `RandomAccessFile` to do what you wish to do. 
Here is a simple snapshot of the code that would demonstrate the use of the the `RandomAccessFile`.

```
package one;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
public class one {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     try
     {
      RandomAccessFile rac = new RandomAccessFile(new File("/home/.../src/one/a.txt"), "r");
      rac.seek(0);
      System.out.println(rac.readLine());
      System.out.println(rac.readLine());
      //Puts the pointer back to first position 
      rac.seek(0);
      System.out.println(rac.readLine());
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
}
```

My a.txt looks like as below:

```
12345678910
212345678910
312345678910
412345678910
512345678910
612345678910
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Lusiathas : Glad that helped. If you were in any case helped by the answer, please upvote the answer as well :)