# how to read integers from a text file again when it read the last value

Tags: java, file

there is a text file like this:

```
>3
>7
>9
>5
```

and i used nexInt() to read all of values. Now i want to read first value again. But when i call nextInt method in this situation, i only get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at files.main(files.java:49)
```

How can I turn the cursor to first line again?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28953928/how-to-set-cursor-at-the-beginning-of-the-txt-file

Comment: Store the numbers in a suitable `Collection` and re-iterate that if necessary...

Comment: Have you tried Scanner.reset()?

Answer (score 0):

You can read your numbers to a list

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
     numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Then read the list like following

```
while(true){
    for(Integer num:numbers){
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Scanner it is not possible however, you can always re-declare the scanner (only if are going to do this reiteration once more).

```
// re-declare
scan = new Scanner(myFile);
```

If you are going to scan the list many times and want to go to and fro, you probably should use RandomAccessFile

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(myFile), "r");
// do something

// later reset to the begining
raf.seek(0);
```

Or save numbers in a List and iterate over it later.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Ways to do that.

You can use:
`if(Scanner.hasNextInt()){}` to avoid getting an Exception and then use the `reset()` function.

Or do like Yohan E said write the Numbers into a List or ArrayList and just Interate over the List.